# GUI problem with ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 16.04, gui

My videos and Downloads folder looks same as normal folder and these are below computer with home and desktop. when I click on videos I get this error as in screenshot.[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kcwia.png)

Comment: Show me the `terminal` output of `ls -al ~/` and `ls -al ~/Desktop`.

Comment: @heynnema this is the output https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B-xmyALupDNLR09zSVgtWGRKMGc
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B-xmyALupDNLY2JvY1U4b0JkU2c

Comment: Unfortunately putting that output into the comments makes it incomplete, and unreadable. Please delete your last comment, and redo the commands, copy/paste the output into your original question, select the text and use the code formatting icon {}, and let me know when that's done so I can look at it.